# Performance issues in finding Hu Moments of Overlapping Blocks in image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation, feature-extraction

I am working on an algorithm (in MATLAB) that needs to find Hu-Moments of overlapping blocks in an image. I am converting image in column matrix **(im2col(...,'sliding'))** and then calculating Hu-Moments for each column individually. For calculating the Hu Moments for the blocks of an Image of **512X512** my system is taking 14-15 minutes. Code is as given below:

```
d=im2col(A,[m n],'sliding');

[mm nn]=size(d);
for j=1:nn
    d_temp=d(:,j);
    d_pass_temp=col2im(d_temp,[n n], [n n], 'distinct');
    [mn_t vr_t]=new_hu_moment(d_pass_temp);
    [mn]=[mn mn_t];
    [vr]=[vr vr_t];
end
```

'new_hu_moment' is my own made function returning mean and variance of hu moments for the respective block.

My sys configuration is I3 processor with 6GB RAM.

1. please suggest for performance up-gradation of this code.
2. is there any function in matlab that can calculate 7 Hu moments for overlapping blocks.

Answer (score 0):

1.preallocate mn and vr before the loop, something like

```
% I suppose that new_hu_moment returns row of known length nvals
mn=zeros(nn,nvals); 
vr=zeros(nn,nvals);
for k=1:nn,
    ...
    [mn(k,:) vr(k,:)]=new_hu_moment(d_pass_temp);
    ...
end
```

I strongly recomend not using i and j as variable names as they are synonyms for imaginary unit. In older MATLAB it can cause errors

2.If you have enough memory and for-loop processes independent data chunks, use parfor or cellfun/arrayfun

3.If code is not as fast you want it to be, use [profiler](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/profiling-for-improving-performance.html) to find the performance bottleneck